# Raw image not detected ExifInterface

Tags: android

I save image from custom camera:

```
public String getFilename() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "Products/Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        String uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        return uriSting;

    }
```

Now:

```
public String saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String filename = getFilename();

        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("Error",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return  filename;

    }
```

I use this filename in exifInterface after saving image

```
exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
```

But every time it shows in my log  `Raw image not detected`, `Exif: 0`

Comment: `file.mkdirs();` Adapt your code. Check the return value of mkdirs an stop if false. Return null. Stop  and display a toast to inform the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compress a bitmap to a jpg file.

Bitmaps dont contain exif information.

And compressing a bitmap to a jpg file does not add an exif header to the file.

Comment: can you tell me other way to get  the image because I use this when I capture `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);` , this will give a bitmap , how can I get something which contains exif information

Comment: FileOutputStream , seems to be the choice then

Comment: ???? You constructed your bitmap from 'data'. So what exactly was in data?

Comment: I will accept your answer once my query is resolved thanks a lot !

Comment: You accepted the wrong answer. Well.. not that it was wrong...

Comment: "Bitmaps dont contain exif information" , that was enough to help me out

Answer (score 0):

> > BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

You have a nice byte array called data.

This byte array contains the bytes of a jpg file with exif header.

If you wanna save the data to file then do not make an intermediate bitmap first as at that moment you lost the exif header.

Instead save the bytes in your data array directly to file.

Then you will have a jpg file with an exif header.